# Define a function that fits some parameters to all of the data and some parameters to subsets of the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lmfit

I have a set of data contained with a pandas dataframe. I am using lmfit to fit multiple equations to this data. Currently I have the code (below) that works.

```
# read in data
df1 = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx',skiprows=0)

#define fit 
def residual(params,Obvs_int,logfO2,Op_b,P,T,uncertainty):
    cS = params['a']
    cH = params['b']
    v0 = params['c']
    v1 = params['d']
    d0 = params['e']
    d1 = params['f']
    e0 = params['g']
    e1 = params['h']
    
    logK = cS + cH/T + Op_b + (v0*P+v1*P**2)/T          
    a0 = d0 + d1*Op_b
    a1= e0 + e1*Op_b
    Calc_int = (1/(1+10**(0.25*logfO2+logK))-a0)/a1
    
    return (Obvs_int-Calc_int)/uncertainty

params = Parameters()
params.add('a',value=-3)
params.add('b',value=5000)
params.add('c',value=300)
params.add('d',value=-97)
params.add('e',value=-0.13)
params.add('f',value=-0.06)
params.add('g',value=1)
params.add('h',value=1)

# run fit
out1 = minimize(residual, params, args=(df1['Obvs_int'],df1['logfO2'],df1['Op_b'],df1['Pressure'], df1['Temperature'],df1['Total_unc']), nan_policy='omit')
```

However, I would now like to fit a subset of my data to the original parameters (cS, cH, d0, d1, e0, e1, v0 and v1) and fit a second subset of my data to the parameters (cS, cH, d0, d1, e0, e1, v2 and v3). Such that the parameters cS, cH, d0, d1, e0 and e1 are evaluated for all of the data but v0 and v1 for one subset and v2 and v3 for the second subset.

I wondered about adding a column to my pandas dataframe with 0 and 1 values to differentiate between the two subsets and then use a if else condition. With the code for my new function reading:

```
def residual(params,Obvs_int,p,logfO2,Op_b,P,T,uncertainty):
    cS = params['a']
    cH = params['b']
    v0 = params['c']
    v1 = params['d']
    d0 = params['e']
    d1 = params['f']
    e0 = params['g']
    e1 = params['h']
    v2 = params['i']
    v3 = params['j']
    
    a0 = d0 + d1*Op_b
    a1= e0 + e1*Op_b
    
    if p == 1:
        logK = cS + cH/T + Op_b + (v0*P+v1*P**2)/T      
        Calc_int = (1/(1+10**(0.25*logfO2+logK))-a0)/a1
    else:
        logK1 = cS + cH/T + Op_b + (v2*P+v3*P**2)/T      
        Calc_int = (1/(1+10**(0.25*logfO2+logK1))-a0)/a1
    
    return (Obvs_int-Calc_int)/uncertainty

params = Parameters()
params.add('a',value=-3)
params.add('b',value=5000)
params.add('c',value=300)
params.add('d',value=-97)
params.add('e',value=-0.13)
params.add('f',value=-0.06)
params.add('g',value=1)
params.add('h',value=1)
params.add('i',value = 300)
params.add('j',value = -97)
```

This doesn't work. The error message I get is 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). I think I get this error because I am passing an entire column of data to the 'if' condition resulting in both true and false values. However, I am not sure how to fix this error, or if a 'if else' condition is the best way to differentiate between the two subsets of data.

Following the comment below I found that adjusting the if else condition to:

```
d = np.where(p==1, v0*P+v1*P**2, v2*P+v3**2)
logK = cS + cH/T + Op_b + (d)/T
```

gives me the desired answer.

Comment: I think as you said, it is processing the whole Series object inside the `residual` function, instead of element by element. So one suggestion would be to use `numpy.where` function. On which the first argument is the condition, which could be `p == 1` applied to your code, the second argument the value it should have in case the condition is `True`, and the third argument the value when the condition evaluates to `False`. But this means you would have to Calc_int in one line, in order to pass it as arguments to `numpy.where`.